# Преобразование строки в словарь

Tags: python, словари

Есть строка по типу `a = '# Игрок Ранг Статус 1 Lenny_Bezkurov X Сейчас играет 2 Mike_Deporto X Не в игре 3 Shon_Blake...'` и так далее.
Можно ли каким либо способом получить из подобной строки словарь? по типу {'#': '1', 'Игрок': 'Mike_Deporto' ...}

Comment: а ключи какие у словаря будут ? или вам нужен словарь из словарей ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В целом через регулярные выражения можно попробовать вытащить данные через `re.findall`.

Первыми вытаскиваем ключи `keys` по маске, потом данные по игрокам `finds`. Потом объединяем все в список словарей `comb`.

```
import re

a = '# Игрок Ранг Статус 1 Lenny_Bezkurov X Сейчас играет 2 Mike_Deporto X Не в игре'
keys = re.findall('^(\S) ([\w]+) ([\w]+) ([\w]+)', a)
finds = re.findall('([\d]+) ([\w]+) ([\w]+) ([\s\D]+)', a)

comb = [dict(zip(*keys, f)) for f in finds]
print(*comb, sep='\n')
```

Вывод:

```
{'#': '1', 'Игрок': 'Lenny_Bezkurov', 'Ранг': 'X', 'Статус': 'Сейчас играет '}
{'#': '2', 'Игрок': 'Mike_Deporto', 'Ранг': 'X', 'Статус': 'Не в игре'}
```

Comment: Спасибо получилось.